# Overwrite rails error message format only for custom error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Is there a way to overwrite the message format only for custom error messages?

I know that it is possible to overwrite rails error message formats at the attribute and model level by using

```
en:   
  errors:
    format: '%{message}'
```

or

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        person:
          format: '%{message}'
```

or

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        person:
          attributes:
            name:
              format: '%{message}'
```

source (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32956).

The issue with this approach, no matter which level the format is overwritten at, this always overwrites the format for all default rails error messages.
If I have a model `Person` with an attribute `name` and I add a en.yml config like

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        person:
          attributes:
            name:
              older_than_eighteen: "You must be older than eighteen"
              format: '%{message}'
```

this now leads to all error message for the name attribute of person being interpolated without the attribute name. If I got some `validate :name, presence: true` the error message for a blank name becomes `can't be blank` instead of `Name can't be blank`.
I know that I could add another error message to the en.yml file above like `blank: "Name can't be blank"` but I would like to avoid that and instead only change the format for my custom error message.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

add into your `config/application.rb`

```
config.active_model.i18n_customize_full_message = true
```

According to [the RoR official docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-model-i18n-customize-full-message):

> **Controls whether the Error#full_message format can be overridden in an i18n locale file. Defaults to false.
> When set to true, full_message will look for a format at the attribute and model level of the locale files**. The default format is "%{attribute} %{message}", where attribute is the name of the attribute, and message is the validation-specific message. The following example overrides the format for all Person attributes, as well as the format for a specific Person attribute (age).